# How can I get list of emails of users who commented on a post?

Tags: comments, users, email

What I want here is simple, but I'm not really sure how to approach it. I have a tournament website based on WordPress, where users sign up for a tournament by commenting on a post.

The problem is, that then I need to send all those guys an email, which means I have to look up 50+ emails for users every single time. I'm thinking of doing some kind of JOIN on the comments and users tables, but I don't really know how to put this in WordPress.

I read somewhere, that if I want to add stuff for users, it should be in a theme, and if I want to add it for administrators, it should be as a plugin, but this looks like it could be a simple script put somewhere.

How would you solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 global $wpdb, $post;
 $query = sprintf("SELECT comment_author_email
                     FROM {$wpdb->comments}
                     JOIN {$wpdb->posts} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->comments}.comment_post_ID
                     WHERE comment_post_ID = %d
                       AND comment_approved = '1'",
                  $post->ID);
 $emails = $wpdb->get_col($query);
 $emails = array_unique($emails);

 // your e-mails
 print_r($emails);
```

You can also use the built-in [`WP_Comment_Query`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.2/wp-includes/comment.php#L186) (or get_comments), but it's going to be a little slower...

Comment: What does `%d` refer to, does it get the value from `global post` ?

Comment: `%d` is the next [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) argument, casted to integer, In this case `$post->ID`. You can replace it with $post->ID, it's the same thing...